# Do transit visitors to Canada require a Quarantine Plan during Covid?

Tags: transit, canada, uk-citizens, covid-19, quarantine

I am a UK citizen planning on transiting through Canada on September 27th on my journey from Mexico City to London Heathrow.

I have 2 hours planned in Toronto, and so do not plan to leave the airport for any reason.

What entry requirements do I need to meet for my trip? Do I need a quarantine plan? I have obtained an ETA already.

I have looked on the website, but the case for transiting visitors is unclear.

Edit to Include website information:
[image: website information]

This would seem to imply that the quarantine plan is mandatory for all travelers, including those that are exempt from travel restrictions

Answer (score 3):

No quarantine for transit passengers. https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/coronavirus-covid19/travel-restrictions-exemptions.html:

> transiting passengers (must remain in the secure transit area of a Canadian airport to complete their connection)

Comment: Thanks, that was how I read it first, though on a second look it reads that the quarantine plan is mandatory for all

Comment: @PatoPan My guess is that "when you arrive in Canada" means that it's only for people who enter Canada, i.e. leave the transit area and pass the immigration checkpoint.